# Ask permission on custom page ionic native push

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I implemented push notification on my ionic application using ionic Push
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/

Currently the application request for permission on application start up.is there any thing we can do it to change with a custom page to ask permission instead of app startup? I am trying to find a solution for this a few days,but i don't find any method in their documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iOS permission prompt is shown when the plugin [registers the app for remote notifications](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m#L283) when the native [init()](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/src/ios/PushPlugin.m#L159) function is called.

So don't call [PushNotification.init()](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/API.md#pushnotificationinitoptions) from JS until you want to show the permission prompt.